# Rewrite wordpress custom taxonomy archive url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, custom-taxonomy

I have many custom post types and custom taxonomies such as "video" custom post type and "video_category", "product" and "product_category" and so on...

All the products are displayed at website.com/shop but if I get to an archive the permalink become website.com/product_category/"categoryname" and the single post has a link like website.com/product/"productname".

I have googled and found out about link rewriting but... don't really know where to start.

I'd like to have the links above become website.com/shop/"categoryname" and website.com/"categoryname"/"productname".
I could simply change the taxonomy name to "shop" for the first case but that would not be really clean, those are categories after all.